# ¿Por qué decimos "apropiar" (sin r) y no "apropriar" si viene del latín "appropriāre"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología

Siempre me cuesta recordar que en inglés se dice *appropriate* (con *r* tras la *p*) y tiendo a escribir <s>appropiate</s> (sin *r*) por su semejanza con la palabra castellano *apropiado*.

Mirando la [etimología de la palabra inglesa](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=appropriate&allowed_in_frame=0) y luego en el DRAE veo que ambas tienen la misma raíz: la palabra latina *approp**r**iāre*.

Curiosamente, el [Mapa de diccionarios de la RAE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) tiene la siguiente información en la entrada de *apropiar* del diccionario de 1780:

> v. a. Hacer propia de alguno qualquier cosa. **Aunque en lo antiguo se dixo APROPRIAR, modernamente se ha omitido con uso comun y constante la segunda R por la suavidad de la pronunciacion**. Rem alicui adjudicare, adscribere.

Entonces la pregunta surge automáticamente: ¿por qué la *r* cayó en el olvido? ¿qué tan común es dejar caer una letra por "suavidad de la pronunciación" cuando el castellano no se caracteriza precisamente por ser un idioma "suave"? (si dudáis, decid en voz alta las *ratas tejen jamones*).

Comment: El idioma no sé, pero las personas tendemos a ir suavizando el lenguaje (te lo dice un andaluz). Yo soy de la firme opinión de que algún día en el futuro se admitirá el uso de los participios sin la "-d-" (_comío_, _bebío_...). :-)

Comment: Lo que constituye "suavidad" va cambiando con el tiempo. Si todo fuera por suavizar y lo suavizado fuese siempre de la misma manera, ya hablaríamos por gruñidos. (Por lo pronto diré que en mi rioplatense, en *las ratas tejen jamones* no queda rastro de ninguna *s*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se trata de un cambio fonético llamado *disimilación* que consiste en

> [**disimilar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DvIWbMq)
> **1.** tr. *Fon.* Alterar la articulación de un sonido del habla diferenciándolo de otro igual o semejante, ya estén ambos contiguos o cercanos. *U. m. c. intr. y c. prnl.*
>
> <sup>Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados</sup>

Es un cambio muy común, tanto en latín (que heredamos) como en español.

Por ejemplo, en latín las terminaciones `-al` y `-alis`, por disimilación cambiaron a `-ar` y `-aris` si la palabra ya tenía `l`. Así tenemos `municipal`, `meridional` y `jovial`, pero `militar`, `auxiliar`, `biliar` y `ocular`. (Hablando de `meridional`, *meridies* (mediodía) es una alteración por disimilación de **medidies*.)

Otros ejemplos son `plegaria` de *precaria*, `hermoso` de *formoso*, `coronel` de *colonel*, `alma` de *anima* (diferenciar las dos nasales)...

Answer (score 2):

Como te comentaba, los andaluces somos expertos en dejar caer letras para darle más suavidad al idioma. De hecho, los franceses son aún más expertos, en francés se omiten multitud de sonidos en la pronunciación (aunque se sigan escribiendo) y así consiguen una pronunciación más fluida. Aquí es común dejar de pronunciar, por ejemplo, las *d* de los participios, o incluso reordenar las letras de una palabra si así la pronunciación es menos trabalenguas (acuérdate de "[murciélago](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q6o8WZ8)" en vez de "murciégalo").

Sobre la propia palabra *apropiar*, es curioso que el texto que mencionas diga "en lo antiguo", cuando en realidad lo antiguo no se refería a hacía mucho tiempo. Me llamó la atención la frase en latín y la busqué, y encontré una referencia al [diccionario de la RAE de 1726](https://books.google.es/books?id=OpKO92-CtLkC&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=Rem%20alicui%20adjudicare,%20adscribere.&source=bl&ots=EFT8g8T6bd&sig=PDdEVJMKgqZ4mQ6RwJx92qw3cq8&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-1uX6gpHPAhWFAxoKHfL4AyIQ6AEIJjAD#v=onepage&q=Rem%20alicui%20adjudicare%2C%20adscribere.&f=false), que se puede consultar en Google Books:

> APROPRIAR. v.a. Destinar, señalar, assignar como própria y perteneciente à alguno una cosa como hacienda, bienes, heréncia &c. lo que en lo forense se llama adjudicar. Este verbo es compuesto de la partícula A y de la palabra Próprio por lo qual y atendiendo à su origen se debe escribir con la r despues de la segunda p, diciendo Apropriar, y no Apropiar, como de ordinario se halla en muchos libros impressos por falta de cúria.

No sólo dice que se debe escribir con la segunda *r*, sino que además achaca falta de cuidado a los que no lo hacen. Se ve que unos cuantos años más adelante dieron marcha atrás y aceptaron la palabra sin dicha *r*. Y por supuesto, cuando eliminaron la segunda *r* de *proprio* lo hicieron con todos sus derivados: *apropiar*, *apropiado*, etc.

Como curiosidad, en italiano se ha mantenido la segunda *r*:

> **[pròprio](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=proprio)**
>
> che appartiene o è relativo a una persona o cosa

Comment: El portugués también lo mantiene: [_apropriado_](http://www.wordreference.com/espt/apropiado) como traducción de _apropiado_

Comment: Según sé, en italiano es muy común (aunque se considera un error) eliminar la segunda *i*.

Comment: @Paco qué curioso, cada cual tiene su forma de suavizar el lenguaje.