# ¿Por qué decimos "ausentar" y no "absentar" si viene del latín "absentāre"?

Tags: etimología, latín

El otro día me fijé en que en catalán decimos [*absentar*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0000720) para la palabra [*ausentar*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4Q023wb), que el DLE identifica como *del latín tardío absentāre*.

Me hizo gracia que se pasara de `abs-` a `aus-` y pensé que era un caso típico de la disimilación que se describe en [¿Por qué decimos “apropiar” (sin r) y no “apropriar” si viene del latín “appropriāre”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18021/1674).

Miré si había ocurrido en otras palabras, buscando por palabras que empiezan por "aus" y "abs" en el DLE. No encontré ninguna ([*austero*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4QHLwSO) viene de *austērus*, por ejemplo), así que la duda me queda: ¿por qué hubo este cambio de `abs` a `aus`? ¿Ocurrió en otros casos?

Comment: No sé si ya viste [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/paso-de-b-a-u-evoluci%c3%b3n-fon%c3%a9tica-o-falta-de-ortograf%c3%ada/25988#25988). Creo que la respuesta aceptada (mía) vale para esta pregunta, aunque el punto de partida sea diferente.

Comment: @pablodf76 tras una lectura rápida me da la sensación de que sí. La marco para leer con calma, pues parece una joya que se me pasó en su momento.

Comment: Releyéndola no agregaría más a lo escrito, salvo el detalle de que hay palabras donde el cambio no se produjo por la razón habitual: que son cultismos (como *abstenerse* o *absorber*).